# How to group data by customized date logic?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date       | Apples | Bananas etc
2020-01-01 | 2      | 5
2020-02-01 | 12     | 44
2020-03-01 | 4      | 45
```

I want to create a grouping logic by date but the date must be transformed to the following:

If the Date is on or after February of the current year, then label the Date as the next respective Year, otherwise label as the current respective year. Example:

For Apples on 2020-01-01, it should be labelled as the year '2020' because it is prior to February of the current year. However, Bananas in 2020-03-01 would be labelled as '2021' because the date falls after February of the current year.

```
Date | Apples | Bananas etc
2020 | 2      | 5
2021 | 12     | 44
2021 | 4      | 45
```

How would this work the best?

Comment: Why are there two rows for 2021?  Shouldn't they be added together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.where` to do a conditional date offset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01'],
 'Apples': [2, 12, 4],
 'Bananas': [5, 44, 45]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Add a year if the month is greater than 1
df['Date'] = np.where(df['Date'].dt.month>1, df['Date']+ pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1), df['Date'])



# If you want the actual dates
print(df.groupby('Date').sum())

            Apples  Bananas
Date                       
2020-01-01       2        5
2021-01-31      12       44
2021-03-01       4       45

# If you want grouped by year only
print(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.year).sum())

      Apples  Bananas
Date                 
2020       2        5
2021      16       89
```

Comment: thanks chris, I actually dont want the to be grouped. In that case, we done need the groupby. I only want the changed year labels in the dataframe. Could you adjust your code please?

Comment: `df` will have what you want, just `print(df)`